# Error generating captcha image on php script

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an algorithm to make captcha validation but the script is returning the error "The image "http://localhost/cptest/captchateste.php" cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

Probably the wrong part is in one of those two loops but I don't have much experience with php and can't go along with it. What can be wrong here? Thanks

```
<?php
session_start();

$width  = 120;
$height =  40;
$length =   5;

$baseList = '0123456789abcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

$code    = "";
$counter = 0;

$image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize GD!');

for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ ) {
   imageline($image,mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height),imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(150,255),mt_rand(150,255), mt_rand(150,255)));
}

for( $i=0, $x=0; $i<$length; $i++ ) {
   $actChar = substr($baseList, rand(0, strlen($baseList)-1), 1);
   $x += 10 + mt_rand(0,10);
   imagechar($image, mt_rand(3,5), $x, mt_rand(5,20), $actChar,imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(0,155), mt_rand(0,155),mt_rand(0,155)));
   $code .= strtolower($actChar);
}
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
$_SESSION['securityCode'] = $code;
?>
```

Comment: So what error your script return? Your code works fine on my laptop.(PHP 5.5.30)

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine in my system. **I don't think there is any problem in displaying the image.** It will be better to run the code again and come back with  the error you are getting. **If you are quite new to php, please use the console window for debugging the script errors .**

Comment: do you know how can I export this generated image to a .jpg image? thanks